# アップロード鍵のリセットについて

Tags: google-play

Googleに問い合わせしたところ、下記のメールが来ました。

しかし、このkeytoolコマンドが認識されないのです。
この手順はほっておいてアップロード鍵のリセット後48時間経ってからら新しいabbファイルをアップロードすればよいのでしょうか？

**Googleからの回答:**

> Google Play デベロッパー様
>
> この度は Google Play デベロッパー サポートにお問い合わせいただきありがとうございます。
> お客様のアプリ（com.kay23.tabletennisrules）のアップロード鍵のリセットについてお手伝いさせていただきます。
>
> なお、アップロード鍵をリセットしてから新しいアップロード鍵を使用できるようになるまでに 48 時間かかることを考慮に入れて計画を立てることをおすすめします。Google Play アプリ署名の使用について詳しくは、ヘルプセンター記事「Google Play アプリ署名を使用する」をご参照ください。
>
> 新しいアップロード鍵を生成して登録する方法は次のとおりです。
>
> Android Studio
> ヘルプセンター記事「アップロード鍵とキーストアを生成する」の手順に沿って、新しい鍵を生成。新しい鍵は、以前の鍵とは異なるものである必要があります。または、次のコマンドラインを使用して新しい鍵を生成することもできます。
>
> ```
> keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks
> ```
>
> この鍵は、25 年間有効な 2048 ビットの RSA 鍵である必要があります。 その鍵の証明書を PEM 形式でエクスポート:
>
> ```
> keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore keystore.jks
> ```
>
> pem ファイルを生成したら、次の手順を行います。 [設定] > [アプリの完全性] > [アプリ署名] に移動します。
> アップロード鍵のリセットをリクエストします。 鍵のリセットをリクエストする理由を説明します。 PEM ファイルを添付します。 [リクエスト]
> をクリックします。 他にご不明な点などございましたらお知らせください。

Comment: 「keytoolコマンドが認識されない」という部分をもう少し説明いただくと、回答が付き易いかと思います。

Comment: 恐らく Windows 環境等で keytool コマンドを指示通り実行しても認識されない…という話なのかなと思います。「keytool コマンド windows」辺りで検索すると解説記事が出てきますが、Java 環境 (JDK or JRE) のインストールが必要なようです。参考: [Windowsでkeytoolを使う方法](https://yougun.jp/use-keytool/) / また、単に PATH が通っていないだけの可能性もあります。

Comment: はい、そう思ってオラクルからダウンロードしましたけど、うまくいかずでした。Google サポートに　このサイトを紹介いただきました。

Comment: あとは、製品を一度削除して、新規にアップロードする方法も可能と聞いています。最悪はその新規アップロードにしようと思いますが、結局問題解決ができないのでここで質問した次第です。

Comment: 「単に PATH が通っていないだけの可能性もあります。」はどこかが分からずです。

Comment: 参考: Windowsでkeytoolを使う方法 　を見ました。　以前オラクルからダウンロードしたものと違うようです。こちらの紹介の物を試してみます。

Comment: 以前はこのサイトhttps://knkomko.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/11/14/015738を参考にしました。こんかいcubickさんが示したものと違いますね。

Answer (score 1):

keytoolはJDK付属のツールなのでJDKを入れて `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` にPATHを通しましょう。

OSがwindowsであれば、コマンドプロンプトで以下のコマンドを実行することでJDKがインストールされPATHも適切に設定されるはずです。
（必要に応じてバージョンは変える)

```
winget install --id=Microsoft.OpenJDK.11
```

インストール後にコマンドプロンプトを改めて起動して `keytool` コマンドを実行してみてください。

Comment: ごめん補足
JDKだけに付属するように読めてしまいますね。JREにも付属しているようなので補足させてください。

Comment: あとわいとサン！！　
keytoolコマンド認識されてました。ありがとうございました。